# How to colour text specifically to string?

Tags: javascript, express, canvas

I am making an image gen endpoint where it `GET`s information about a Minecraft Server User's statistics. I'm sorry if this gets confusing but i'll do my best.

What I am trying to do here is to make the colour of the text correspond to `hive.modernRank.human` JSON object key. So for example:

- If `hive.modernRank.human` returns the value as Ultimate Premium, it would be coloured Pink
  or
- If `hive.modernRank.human` returns the value as Emerald, it would be coloured Green

etc.

Currently, its just black text because I am not sure how to implement this and therefore, I am starting out with making the endpoint.

Code:

```
   try {       
   Canvas.registerFont(resolve(join(__dirname, '../assets/RifficFree-Bold.ttf')), 'Riffic');  
   Canvas.registerFont(resolve(join(__dirname, '../assets/GothamMedium.ttf')), 'GothamMedium');

const { body: hive } = await get(`http://api.hivemc.com/v1/player/${req.query.player}`)
    const { body: template } = await get(`https://i.imgur.com/XccpQSv.png`)
    const { width, height } = await loadImage(template); 

          let canvas = new Canvas(width, height)
    .addImage(template, 0, 0, width, height)
    .setColor("#000000")
    .setTextFont(`30px Riffic`)
    .addText(hive.username, 20, 40)
    .setTextFont(`14px GothamMedium`)

    .setColor(`#`)
    .addText(hive.modernRank.human, 20, 60)
  /*  .setColor("#ffffff")
    .setTextFont(`20px GothamMedium`)*/
  /*  .addText(`
XP: ${hide.xp}
Hider Kills: ${hide.hider_kills} • Seeker Kills: ${hide.seeker_kills}
Played: ${hide.played} • Wins: ${hide.victories} • Deaths: ${hide.deaths}
W/L: ${wlratio}% • HK/D: ${hdratio} • SK/D: ${sdratio}
First Played: ${date}
`, 20, 89)*/

    .toBuffer();

    res.contentType('image/png');
    res.end(canvas)
     } catch (e) { 
    return res.send({"error": "404 Not Found", "message": "The Hive Bedrock player you tried to request was not found. Make sure the player username was spelt correct."});     
        }
```

Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Dl43.jpg

Note that the project is done with express.js routing. Screenshots for your information. I am asking here because I do not want to end up writing 300 more lines of duplicated code just for the Rank Colour.

Comment: you have `.setColor("#000000")` can you not change that to suit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `.setColor` works fine for me...
See code below I'm randomly picking a color (red or green) that will be applied to the second text:

```
const { Canvas } = require("canvas-constructor");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let color = "#FF0000";
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    color = "#00FF00";
  }

  let canvas = new Canvas(200, 200)
    .setColor("#000000")
    .addText("Hello", 20, 40)
    .setColor(color)
    .addText("World", 20, 60);

  res.contentType("image/png");
  res.end(canvas.toBuffer());
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Service running PORT:" + PORT);
});
```

In your case the if statement will be checking the value of modernRank

Here is that in action:
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-snow-exxdr?file=/server.js

Comment: This seems to work great. I've tested it, however. There is one specific string in modernRank that has more than one color. Its called "Master of Disguise" And are coloured differently for each word. Any thought? Thanks for your response

Comment: @NTMNathan the `one specific string that has more than one color` you will have to split that into two and color each individually